# Shellscript Error handling

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, centos

I'm coding a very simple shell that deletes files of a given folder, in this case all .csv files that lives in that folder.

The code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Used to clean folder

MinVal=0
Files=$(ls -1 *.csv | wc -l)


if [ $Files -gt $MinVal ];then
        rm *.csv
        echo -e "\e[31;43m***** DONE *****\e[0m"    

 else       
        echo -e "\e[31;43mThere is no valid file to delete, please check\e[0m"      


fi
```

The shell script works as expected, but when you execute the shell and there is no .csv files in the folder the terminal says the following:

```
ls: cannot access *.csv: No such file or directory
```

off course it also shows the `else` message:

```
There is no valid file to delete, please check
```

Is there any way to avoid the `ls: cannot access *.csv: No such file or directory` and get straight to the to the `else` error handling?

Greetings.

Comment: What should happen if there are .csv files but they couldn't be deleted (e.g. permissions)? Right now your script just will say "DONE" as if all is well. There are other less common but possible errors, like if a directory called  foo.csv exists, rm will try to delete it but will fail.

Comment: It is a possibility for sure but for this scenario there's no need to go that deep, It's outside of the scope

Comment: Looking at your `rm -r` as well as your comment, chances are you want simply a recursive deletion:   `find . -type f -iname '*.csv' -delete`  Also printing things like "DONE" is against Unix convention and a bad idea.

Answer (score 8):

This happens because `*.csv` is passed verbatim to `ls` by the shell, which is default POSIX behaviour. If you want to avoid this, you should use `nullglob` so that globs that return nothing return nothing instead of returning the verbatim string entered. This has a problem though, because `ls` has different behaviour when no files are provided.

Try this instead, which has the benefit of avoiding bugs in the case of embedded newlines in filenames:

```
shopt -s nullglob
filenames=( *.csv )  # put all files in an array
files="${#filenames[@]}"  # get number of files
```

Comment: I haven't use arrays yet but I will give that a try, It makes the code very elegant, thank you

Comment: How do people remember these bizarre BASH constructions? They seem like magical incantations that would need to be googled each time you want to use them.

Comment: @BallpointBen The same way you learn any other language, by using it a lot :-) Bash is not perfect, but it's not completely unintelligible either. It ended up this way for a bunch of reasons.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is suppress the warning message from `ls` then the most straight-forward thing to do would be to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`, e.g.:

```
Files=$(2>/dev/null ls -1 *.csv | wc -l)
```

Note that redirecting `stderr` will suppress **all** errors resulting from this command, including errors that may not be related to the absence of `*.csv` files in the directory.

A better solution for counting files might be to use `find` instead of `ls`, e.g.:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" | wc -l
```

In fact, you might want to use `find` to perform the deletion as well:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -delete
```

I also noticed that you used the `-r` flag with `rm`, which looks like it may be unintentional, since you're performing a flat search using `ls` followed by a recursive delete with `rm`.

Frankly though, I'm not sure that it makes a lot of sense to write a script for this task. What benefit does this script offer over just running the commands directly? In other words, what's wrong with this:

```
# Check for files
ls *.csv

# Delete the files
rm *.csv
```

Why is running your script better than running these commands? It looks like you're just adding overhead and replacing one error message with another.

Comment: This will also suppress other errors -- for example, if the current cwd is invalid, there are I/O errors, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for the information, actually your first solution works pretty well, I will try the `find` at home because that command doesn't exist in the production server.

Comment: @ChrisDown You're right, of course. But I feel pretty strongly that the first part of a response should always answer the question as asked and provide the simplest and most direct possible solution. Any additional caveats, subtlety, etc. should follow that first simple solution. Personally I think that if someone is trying to write a program that has robust error-handling then they probably shouldn't be doing it in pure Bash anyway. Anyway, thanks for the comment. I'll add a note - upvoted.

Comment: @sandatomo, if this is for a production script, *please* just use the `rm *.csv` command.  And consider whether you want the dotglob option set.